# Does a C# Generics class casting similar to Java Generics class casting exist?

Tags: c#, generics

The code below is what I use for a java program to cast a generic to a specific. I understand there is no wild cards in C# but was hoping somebody can point me in the right direction as how I can modify the code to be similar to java:

```
public <T extends GameComponent<?>>T getComponent(int id, Class<T> type){
    return type.cast(components.get(id));
}
```

Comment: The question title makes it sound like you're looking for a Java equivalent to something in C#, but it's the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

Looks as something like:

```
public T GetComponent<T>(int id) where T : GameComponent
{
    return components[id] as T;
}
```

Thanks for everyone in the comments, helping me fix my solution (as I was way off).
I couldn't have been here without you guys.
And I'll miss you.

<3

But really, thanks :D

Comment: hi Yorye. Thanks for the help, but where exactly does .cast() come from? Is this a method i have to create myself in the GameComponent.class? Sorry for such stupid questions, am just starting to learn C#

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but the syntax of the method body isn't valid C#.

Comment: @Alan I fixed the body. I just thought cast was a method for some reason, but then I remembered some more java, hehe.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: your Java skill is still shining through with that get() call :) How about fixing it to this: public T GetComponent<T>(int id, T type) where T: GameComponent
    {
      return (T) components[id];
    }  (because we don't even know if it's in a generic class or just a generic method in itself)

Comment: @Alan Yes, I failed here big time, ^.^"

Comment: It looks like the GameComponent is a generic class, there's an unbounded wildcard in the definition. Your C# equivalent seems incorrent to me then.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I failed big time anyways, suggest your own solution so OP can view it as well.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: Well, I suggested the extra <T> because I wasn't sure, but you have a point. Also, while we are at it, I think the original Java code throws when the cast is invalid, so the "as" operator is not semantically equivalent.

Comment: @Alan True, I thought more into what will probably be better rather than doing exactly what the java code does (regardless to the fact I forgot all about java's syntax)

Comment: @YoryeNathan: Oh, I fully understand you wanted the best for the OP. It's a bit subjective, though---I for one would prefer having the invalid cast exception thrown right here instead of trudging along with a null and potentially throw in some distant location, causing wild head scratches...

Comment: I don't have the compiler at hand and can't validate whether this compiles in c#: `public T GetComponent<T, U>(int id, T type) where T : GameComponent<U>` but it is closer to the Java version than the version with one open type.

Comment: +1 @WiktorZychla Seems like it would compile, and a nice addition. By the way there's a nice online compiler [here](http://www.frosthawk.net/)

Comment: Actually that `type` parameter is quite pointless. Just remove it entirely. The function should be called as `GetComponent<CoolGameComponent>(1337)` then.

Comment: @Wormbo Oh yeah! I didn't notice that the type parameter isn't really used. Thanks, fixed! Man my answer was really off XD

Comment: @Yorye: you could probably modify your answer to at least mention this discussion.

Comment: Thinking about it some more, that should probably not contain the `where` and cast to `T`. The `where` would have to be dropped entirely and the cast and return type should be `GameComponent<T>`, which would reflect the Java code precisely.